# Argparse without calling the script every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

So at the moment when I want to use a program with argparse, in the terminal I have to do

```
python scriptname.py --arg 1
```

I was wondering if there is any way of making so that all I have to type is:

```
--arg 1
```

It would make using it easier and look neater. Thanks.

Comment: How would that even theoretically work?

Comment: @Tagc well the way i thought would be somehow 'being inside the script' so that when you use an argument it knows to run from that program

Comment: Might also be worth taking a look at the [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) module, this makes it easy to write line-based interpreters (e.g. you would start your script, then just type commands to pass to it).

Comment: What you could do is execute the script once and the script asks for the arguments using `input` inside a loop. This way you only have to type `python scriptname.py` once and you can run it multiple times with different arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is not possible, because you have to specify which program to run, before you can give it any arguments.

However, if your goal is to reduce the number of keystrokes:

- you could give your script a short name if you're interested in reducing the number of keystrokes.
- you could add the following line to the start of your script

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  ```

  make it executable, run the following from the command line,

  ```
  >chmod a+x scriptname
  ```

  and then call the script like this:

  ```
  >./scriptname --arg 1
  ```
- if you have only 1 argument, you could also omit the `--arg`.

But there's no way for the system to know which script you want to call based on the argument you pass to it.